nginx: restrict proxied IP access?
We are using cloudflare proxy, so real IP is hidden. But if you would know real IP, you can still access site using it. Is there a way to limit access by that IP?
I mean:

by domain: https://some-domain.com -> OK
by proxy IP: https://1.2.3.4 -> OK
by real IP: https://5.6.7.8 -> to restrict.

Or it is pointless to try to restrict it?
Sample of nginx.conf server blocks:
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name some-domain.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    charset utf-8;
    server {
        server_name some-domain.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ...
        ...
    }


It isn't pointless, and there is a way to do it. However some [SO] users hates the nginx tag (although the docker tag, which has no more to do with programming, for some reason does not bother them). There were some hot discussions on meta about this at the time. Ask the same question on [SF] and I'll answer it.

@IvanShatsky here is same question on server fault: https://serverfault.com/questions/1169566/nginx-restrict-proxied-ip-access yeah its quite ambiguous what is expected to be asked on stack overflow..:)
